# Can Google Tag Manager add head pixels?

Tags: google-tag-manager

While TM is loaded in a webpage's body, can it still be used to add pixels to a webpage's head?
Note that sometimes it's just a *recommendation* (e.g. Facebook Remarketing pixel), but other times it's mandatory (e.g. Facebook Conversion pixel).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. 
Google Tag Manager code is below the body tag, but that doesn't mean the custom HTML tags are loaded there too. Actually it loads them in the head by default.

Comment: How can you tell? Can you modify that default?

Comment: Actually a quick look at my code showed me that. Most of the scripts that i load with Custom HTML were loaded in the head. But unfortunately i have no idea how to modify the default.

Comment: But your code is only loaded externally so how can you tell it's in the header? It's not like you can view your page's source and quickly search for it.

Comment: you can actually take a look at the loaded code with Firebug and check it quick and easy.